# How to use node package in my website?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm working on project which is in angularjs . I want to use a node module in current running angular project, how i will added node module in this project.

Comment: Are you using NPM? Install it through NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `npm` then `npm install <package_name>` to install package. this will install the package to the node_modules folder by default

Then include via script tag in your index.html

`<script src="./path/to/node_module/package.js"></script>`

or for styles  use

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/node_module/package.css">`

Comment: when i use npm install <package_name> to install package i get more folders from node but didn't get any package.js file

Comment: package.js is just a dummy name I provided search for the folder named with your package name and include the file you want. I would suggest you to go through npm first

Comment: Simply i want to ask you one thing i need to include socket.io from node module and folder structure is following node_modules/socket.io/ in this there is index.js and lib folder so which file i need to be add ?

Comment: go to the developer's website and check for the instructions. it may differ for packages.  Mostly it will be in `dist/` or `lib/` folder. in your case I think it is in `lib/socket.js`.

Comment: accept and close this answer once you got any resolution.

Comment: I will say that is the answer to your question. you are expecting something else. if you are a beginner go through some tutorials or check some beginners guide before you start.